# youtube YTPlayerView not responding

Tags: ios, youtube-api

YTPlayerView code snippet

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.playerView setDelegate:self];
    [self.playerView loadVideoByURL:@"https://www.youtube.com/embed/xyz" startSeconds:2.0 suggestedQuality:kYTPlaybackQualityAuto];
}
```

Comment: not even delegates of ytplayerView has been called

Comment: i am playing this under playViewDidBecomeReady delegate as
[self.playerView playVideo];

Comment: i am following this
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper

Comment: Do not use `kYTPlaybackQualityAuto` as a quality selection for regular videos.  `kYTPlaybackQualityAuto` is only used by Live Events.  https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper/pull/56

Comment: @smnkhan Any luck figuring it out?

Answer (score -1):

I have found that class to be outdated and hard to use.
here was my solution (no delegates though)

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.youtube.com/embed/%@",tubeId]];
UIWebView *web = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:webFrame];
[self.view addSubview:web];
[web loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
```

Comment: i can play video in webview , but it only plays in full screen i want to play it also in inline view

Comment: actually it is not playing in webview .. :(

Comment: oh i have to use VPN as youtube was blocked here in Pakistan

Comment: The only thing left is to play this also in inline  . .  any simplest way to do this ?